# maven dependency error when i start to install mvn -nsu

Tags: maven, build, dependencies, opendaylight

Failed to execute goal on project netconf-exercise-impl: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.sdnhub.odl.tutorial.netconf-exercise:netconf-exercise-impl:bundle:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: openexi:nagasena:jar:0000.0002.0053.0, openexi:nagasena-rta:jar:0000.0002.0053.0: Failure to find openexi:nagasena:jar:0000.0002.0053.0 in http://nexus.opendaylight.org/content/repositories/opendaylight.release/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of opendaylight-release has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]

Comment: Check if the given artifact really exists and remove the folder from your local cache first $HOME/.m2/repository/... afterwards rebuilt.

Comment: The following artifacts could not be resolved: openexi:nagasena:jar:0000.0002.0053.0, openexi:nagasena-rta:jar:0000.0002.0053.0: Failure to find openexi:nagasena:jar:0000.0002.0053.0 in http://nexus.opendaylight.org/content/repositories/opendaylight.release/ was cached in the local repository,

Answer (score 2):

Yeap, had the exact same error, but copying the settings.xml from the official ODL wiki did it for me.

Just used this command from the wiki's instructions:

`wget -q -O - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/opendaylight/odlparent/master/settings.xml > ~/.m2/settings.xml`

Answer (score 1):

Same issue here.  I am actively searching for an alternative jar location for nagasena and nagasena-rta so we can just update the repository list.

Comment: Well, I found an odd work around.  I downloaded their virtual box image and loaded it up.  That VM's ".m2" directory had both the nagasena jars that are missing.

Comment: I scp'd it down from the VM to my .m2 directory by hand, totally ridiculous.  I ran into problems after this, and just gave up and used the VM exclusively.

Comment: I figured out a better solution.  They have extra settings needed for maven (settings.xml) it includes the repos needed for compliation.

https://wiki.opendaylight.org/view/GettingStarted:Development_Environment_Setup

Answer (score 1):

According to the OpenDaylight Wiki. You need to

Edit your ~/.m2/settings.xml

OpenDaylight maintains its own repositories outside of Maven Central, which means maven cannot resolve OpenDaylight artifacts by default. Since OpenDaylight is organized as multiple inter-dependent projects, building a particular project usually means pulling in some artifacts. In order to make this work, your maven installation needs to know the location of OpenDaylight repositories and has to taught to use them.

This is achieved by making sure ~/.m2/settings.xml looks something like the copy kept in odlparent. You can do that quickly with the following command"

```
cp -n ~/.m2/settings.xml{,.orig} ; \
wget -q -O - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/opendaylight/odlparent/master/settings.xml > ~/.m2/settings.xml
```

## after this you can then re-run mvn -nsu

```
 “mvn clean install -nsu”
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by ShamanPrime and user2719303, you must configure your env with a custom `~/.m2/settings.xml` file.

Full instructions are here:  https://wiki.opendaylight.org/view/GettingStarted:Development_Environment_Setup